# Matrix whose eigenvectors are Hermite polynomials

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra

I first constructed a symmetric matrix as the Laplacian operator, and its eigenvectors are a series of harmonics functions as expected. I programmed it and convinced myself. The matrix looks like:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1& -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1& 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0& -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0& 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
0& 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\end{array}\right)
$$
multiplying this matrix with $\{x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\}$ leads to $\{x_0-x_1, -x_0+2x_1-x_2,-x_1+2x_2-x_3,..\}$; The term $-x_{i-1}+2x_i-x_{i+1}$ is equivalent to the second order derivative (in the Laplacian) on a discrete 1-dimensional domain: $(x_i-x_{i-1})-(x_{i+1}-x_i)$.

Everything works fine until I try to construct the matrix for Hermite polynomials. Wiki says the operator is 
$$
L[u]=u''-xu'=-\lambda u.\tag1
$$
I think the matrix for the first derivative should be
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
1& -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0& 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)
$$
however, combining this new matrix with the Laplacian matrix (according to $(1)$) does not produce the expected eigenvectors.

Another source derives polynomial from the operator
$$
H=-\frac12\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac12x^2,
$$
but what are the matrix entries for $x^2$?

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this a pure mathematics question? Please make a connection to a compute science topic! (Also, please come up with a more descriptive title.)

Comment: Alternatively, if this should have been on Math.SE, you can click "flag" to flag it for moderator attention and ask the moderators to migrate it to Math.SE.

Comment: Ahh, I see: [This was also posted on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1440817/14578).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.